# Exception: HttpResponseError: (BadRequest) Entity [pipeline_name] not found

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I created a pipeline in Azure Data Factory that takes an Avro file and creates a SQL table from it. I already tested the pipeline in ADF, and it works fine. Now I need to trigger this pipeline from an Azure function: to do this, I'm trying to create a run of the pipeline using the following code within the function:

```
import logging
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    from .config import suscription_id, resource_group, factory_name, pipeline_name
    client = DataFactoryManagementClient(
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
        subscription_id=suscription_id,
    )
    logging.info('==== ADF client created ====')

    response = client.pipelines.create_run(
        resource_group_name=resource_group,
        factory_name=factory_name,
        pipeline_name=pipeline_name,
    )
    logging.info(response)
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Pipeline {pipeline_name} started")
```

But for some reason, I'm getting an error message saying that finding the resource is impossible, referring to the pipeline. I already verified all the names, and everything seems correct. Do you have any suggestions to debug this?

```
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.591Z] Executed 'Functions.restoreTable' (Failed, Id=c00a9f36-695d-4806-bb6d-880ac88f1d95, Duration=7398ms)
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.591Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.restoreTable. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.591Z] Exception: HttpResponseError: (BadRequest) Entity Restore_backup not found
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.591Z] Code: BadRequest
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.591Z] Message: Entity Restore_backup not found
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.591Z] Target: pipeline/Restore_backup/runid/65350dbc-d9b4-11ed-8e61-acde48001122
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.591Z] Stack:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5095/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 452, in _handle__invocation_request
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.591Z]     call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.591Z]   File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 52, in run
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.591Z]     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.591Z]   File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5095/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 718, in _run_sync_func
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.591Z]     return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context,
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.591Z]   File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5095/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.591Z]     result = function(**args)
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.591Z]   File "/Users/jd/Documents/globant-api/restoreTable/__init__.py", line 14, in main
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.591Z]     response = client.pipelines.create_run(
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.592Z]   File "/Users/jd/Documents/globant-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 76, in wrapper_use_tracer
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.592Z]     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.592Z]   File "/Users/jd/Documents/globant-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/mgmt/datafactory/operations/_pipelines_operations.py", line 937, in create_run
[2023-04-13T04:34:00.592Z]     raise HttpResponseError(response=response, error_format=ARMErrorFormat)
```

**UPDATE**

I believe there is a conflict with the credentials that my app is trying to use. I already added my Azure account to the Vscode login and installed the Azure CLI to log in there. Still, once I try to hit the endpoint with Postman, a dialog opens up to ask for permission to use the Azure credentials in Keychain:

[image]

When I decline the request, I get this message

```
2023-04-13T18:18:56.002Z] DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.002Z] Attempted credentials:
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.002Z]      EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.002Z] Visit https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot to troubleshoot.this issue.
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.003Z]      ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no response from the IMDS endpoint.
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.003Z]      SharedTokenCacheCredential: Authentication failed: 
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.003Z] To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot.
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z] Executed 'Functions.restoreTable' (Failed, Id=3c3d2f26-1d37-4b0f-a94e-b3d4d4978c08, Duration=21193ms)
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.restoreTable. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z] Exception: ClientAuthenticationError: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z] Attempted credentials:
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z]      EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z] Visit https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot to troubleshoot.this issue.
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z]      ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no response from the IMDS endpoint.
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z]      SharedTokenCacheCredential: Authentication failed: 
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z] To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot.
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z] Stack:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5095/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 452, in _handle__invocation_request
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z]     call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z]   File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 52, in run
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z]     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z]   File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5095/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 718, in _run_sync_func
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z]     return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context,
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z]   File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5095/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z]     result = function(**args)
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z]   File "/Users/jd/Documents/globant-api/restoreTable/__init__.py", line 14, in main
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.128Z]     response = client.pipelines.create_run(
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]   File "/Users/jd/Documents/globant-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 76, in wrapper_use_tracer
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]   File "/Users/jd/Documents/globant-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/mgmt/datafactory/operations/_pipelines_operations.py", line 929, in create_run
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]     pipeline_response: PipelineResponse = self._client._pipeline.run(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]   File "/Users/jd/Documents/globant-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 202, in run
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]     return first_node.send(pipeline_request)
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]   File "/Users/jd/Documents/globant-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 70, in send
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]     response = self.next.send(request)
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]   File "/Users/jd/Documents/globant-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 70, in send
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]     response = self.next.send(request)
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]   File "/Users/jd/Documents/globant-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 70, in send
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]     response = self.next.send(request)
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]   [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]   File "/Users/jd/Documents/globant-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/mgmt/core/policies/_base.py", line 46, in send
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]     response = self.next.send(request)
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]   File "/Users/jd/Documents/globant-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_redirect.py", line 156, in send
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]     response = self.next.send(request)
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]   File "/Users/jd/Documents/globant-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_retry.py", line 448, in send
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]     response = self.next.send(request)
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]   File "/Users/jd/Documents/globant-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_authentication.py", line 108, in send
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]     self.on_request(request)
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]   File "/Users/jd/Documents/globant-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_authentication.py", line 87, in on_request
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]     self._token = self._credential.get_token(*self._scopes)
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]   File "/Users/jd/Documents/globant-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/identity/_credentials/default.py", line 168, in get_token
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]     return super(DefaultAzureCredential, self).get_token(*scopes, **kwargs)
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]   File "/Users/jd/Documents/globant-api/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/identity/_credentials/chained.py", line 101, in get_token
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z]     raise ClientAuthenticationError(message=message)
[2023-04-13T18:18:56.129Z] .
```

When I accept the request, I get the initial message that says that I can´t find the resource (the pipeline), and that makes sense if this is using the credentials of a different account that doesn't have my pipeline. How can I force the code to take the Vscode or CLI credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the below code to trigger my ADF pipeline that takes the avro file and creates an SQL Table from it:-

**My init.py file:-**

```py
import logging
import os
import json
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest, res: func.Out[func.HttpResponse]) -> None:
    try:
        # Load configuration values from config.json
        with open(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config.json')), 'r') as f:
            config = json.load(f)

        # Create Data Factory Management Client
        client = DataFactoryManagementClient(
            credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
            subscription_id=config['subscription_id']
        )
        logging.info('ADF client created')

        # Trigger Pipeline
        run_response = client.pipelines.create_run(
            resource_group_name=config['resource_group_name'],
            factory_name=config['factory_name'],
            pipeline_name=config['pipeline_name']
        )

        # Return response
        res.set(func.HttpResponse(f"Pipeline run_id {run_response.run_id} created"))
        
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(str(e))
        res.set(func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500))
```

**My config.json file:-**

```json
{

"subscription_id": "<subscription-id>",

"resource_group_name": "<resource-group-name>",

"factory_name": "<adf-name>",

"pipeline_name": "pipeline6"

}
```

**My function.json**

```json
{

"bindings": [

{

"name": "req",

"type": "httpTrigger",

"direction": "in",

"authLevel": "anonymous",

"methods": [

"post"

]

},

{

"type": "http",

"direction": "out",

"name": "res"

}

],

"scriptFile": "__init__.py",

"entryPoint": "main"

}
```

**My requirements.txt:-**

```
azure-functions

azure-mgmt-datafactory

azure-identity
```

I used the HTTP post request that finds the config.json from function directory which has ADF and pipeline details and triggers the pipeline, Refer below:-

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

**Post request in Postman:-**

[image]

**Portal:-**

***Avro file to SQL pipeline:-***

[image]

[image]

***Pipeline triggered successfully via Azure Function:-***

[image]

***Avro file got added in SQL table like below:-***

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response! It seems like we are doing pretty similar stuff, so I´m starting to think that my problem is related to the DefaultAzureCredentials: It is not taking into account the VScode credentials, nor the CLI ones

Comment: After logging into your account with az login, Make sure you use this command to set your subscription- az account set --subscription "Azure CXP Community Internal Consumption"