Triggering Synapse Data Ingestion Pipeline from Power BI: Button/Power Apps Integration Issue
I want to be able to execute my Synapse data ingestion pipeline from a dedicated Power BI report using a button or Power Apps.
I tried creating an Azure Function App with an HTTP trigger but couldn't get it to work.
How can I execute my pipeline using an Azure Function?

@Djbril Diakhate Can you share the code of the Http Trigger you tried? Also refer my SO answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76001688/exception-httpresponseerror-badrequest-entity-pipeline-name-not-found/76003807#76003807 where I create one ADF pipeline, I can share similar code to execute your synapse pipeline.

Microsoft announced a visual in PowerBI to do just that: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-automate-visual-ga-embed-workflows-directly-within-your-power-bi-reports/
